# How to create a formula that searches multiple pieces of information within a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create conditional formatting based on the results of a "compatibility" chart. I would like to be able to reference a cell at the top of the spreadsheet, for example "A1". For instance IF A1 = 1, 5, or 7, and the second reference cell (for example B1) is 1, 5, or 7, then I want the current cell to return "Natural" and be highlighted green. If "B1" is 2,3,or 9, then I want the current formula to return "Compatible". If "B1 is 4 or 6, I want it to return "Challenge". If "B1" is 8, I want the formula to return "Neutral". In addition to this, I would like to know how to add other conditions to "A1" in addition to the ones above. For instance: If "A1" is 2, 4, 8 followed by the conditions, and again for if "A1" is 3,6,9, followed by the conditions.  If the result is "Natural", I want the cell to be highlighted Green, if "Compatible", I want a yellow highlight, and a red highlight for "Challenge".

Would it be best to use a VLOOKUP table?

Here are the tables I want to reference. I initially wanted to use Table 2, but figured it would be easier to use Table 1

compatibility excel tables

[image]

Comment: You can use Index/Match on table 1 to return the value, then conditional formatting to apply the cell color.  https://exceljet.net/formula/two-way-lookup-with-index-and-match

Comment: Thank you so much! It works exactly the way I wanted it to.